# New links in Sharepoint containing spaces include %2520

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I create new links on our Intranet Sharepoint page, if the target file has spaces in it then after the link is created the final result for something like File name becomes File%2520Name. Old links are still using the standard %20 method and work fine. These new links however, are broken. From what I read, %25 is a % so somewhere, Sharepoint is randomly seeing an additional one of those? My steps for adding a new link to a file are: Edit page > Insert > Link > From address. I put in the full file path and precede it with `file://` and the end result is a file path with %2520. My only "fix" for this so far has been to rename files to remove the spaces. Any thoughts?

Comment: You are experiencing double encoding. Are you copy pasting the name from somewhere? In some cases this includes hidden characters, unless you explicitly include the %20 in the name without would be encoded again to the above.

Comment: I was copying and pasting out of word. For example; I open a document, click File and then copy the file path. But, when I just manually typed the path in, it still changed the space to be %2520.

Comment: When typing the link are you explicitly writing %20 or do you only press space for the space?

Comment: I actually tried both methods just to see what happens. I was putting in just a standard space and would get %2520. If I explicitly write in %20 then I still end up with %2520.

Comment: Does your solution have any extra custom functionality for presenting the link? For example the Intranet page applying the extra encoding to the link when it is presented?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue only occurs in one file name, then you could rename the file to remove the spaces.

Then to troubleshoot the issue, you could paste the URL of the file to the text file and then paste the URL of the file to the link in the page.